# Show that the following group $H$ is a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $a,b$ be fixed positive integers and $H=\{ax+by:x,y\in \mathbb Z \}$. Show that $H$ is a cyclic group with $\gcd(a,b)$ as a generator.

**Proceed**
Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$.  What can I say after this?

**Added**
 A group $G $ is said to be cyclic if   there exists an element $a$ in $G$ such that 
$$G=\{ a^n: n\in \mathbb Z\}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $d$ is *any* common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $a = kd$ and $b = \ell d$ for some integers $k$ and $\ell$.

   So for any element $ax + by \in H$, $$ax + by = (kd)x + (\ell d)y = (kx+\ell y)d$$
   which shows that every element in $H$ is a multiple of $d$.
2. If $d$ is the *greatest* common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then (Bézout's identity) there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = d$. Multiply this equation by any integer $n$; we have that $a(nx) + b(ny) = nd$, which shows that every multiple of $d$ is in $H$.
3. If every element in $H$ is a multiple of $d$, and every multiple of $d$ is in $H$, it follows that $H$ is exactly the set of all multiples of $d$:

$$H \equiv \{nd : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: I think you want to re-associate in the last line of 2: $(an)x+(bn)y=nd.$ As Doug M points out in the answer below, you should show that $H$ is in fact a subgroup of $G,$ but this is easy since $H$ is closed under subtraction.

Comment: @Chris, well, $d\mathbb Z$ is known to be a subgroup.

Comment: @Chris, I associate it that way to show that it has the form ax+by, proving that it's in H. To prove that H is a group, it's enough to show that it has the same set of elements and binary operator as another known group (here, the cyclic group generated by d).

Comment: @Ennar- Fair point, That would do it, if the OP mentioned it in  his or her solution. Perhaps I'm being pedantic, and I certainly don't want to be.

Comment: @user326210 - Your subgroup point is well-taken.

Answer (score 1):

We need to establish that $H$ is a group.

And that every element in the group, can be expressed as $nd$

$d = \gcd(a,b)$ implies that there exist some $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ax + by = d$

Since $ax + by = d \implies d \in H$

and

$a(2x) + b(2y) = 2d \implies 2d \in H$

$nd \in H \implies nd + d = (n+1)d \in H$

$0$ is the identity 
$-d + d = 0 \implies -d$ is the inverse of $d$ and every element $nd$ has an inverse element$-nd.$

We have established that $H$ is a group.

Now we need to show that there is no element in $H$ that cannot be expressed as $nd$

By the definition of $\gcd(a,b)$ there is no $x,y$ such that $0<ax + by < d$

Suppose there is some element in $h\in H$ that not equal to $nd$

and $x', y'\in \mathbb Z$ such that $ax' + by' = h$

Then for some $n, nd<h<(n+1)d$
and $h-nd < d$
then $a(x'-nx) + b(y'-ny)<d$
Contradicting that there is no $x,y$ such that $0<ax + by < d$